# Watchkit interfaceController for interfaceControllerID:random Not Found

Tags: interface-builder, watchkit, xcode10

Developing a new stand-alone WatchKit 5 app in Xcode 10.1
I am just cleaning up now that features added and bugs squashed, and the App runs fine with no crashes etc. However, I get two debugger alert when running on Sim or hardware:

```
    2019-01-15 12:10:56.907672-0500 
App WatchKit Extension[7263:261438] 
[default] -[SPRemoteInterface _interfaceControllerWithID:]:2087: 
ComF: interfaceController for interfaceControllerID:1C5F0002 not found 
(clientIdentifier=(null))
```

Prior SO discussion of this error does not seem to apply since

1. Occurs before **applicationDidFinishLaunching()**
2. All scenes in storyboard have names, storyboardID's and correct modules (all inherit from Target). All except Static Notification view which does not allow for module entry
3. I am not using anything that need handling in didDeactivate like MMWormHole
4. The app is strictly Page-based Nav. There are no pushController calls.
5. I never explicitly call **reloadRootControllersWithNames**.
6. Looking at storyboard source shows all controllers have appropriate "customModule"
7. Never renamed WatchKit Target

Trying to check out the calling arguments inside watchkit (po $arg1 etc.) fails with an $arg1 not declared

```
WatchKit`-[SPRemoteInterface _interfaceControllerWithID:]:
->  0x225977 <+0>:   pushl  %ebp
    0x225978 <+1>:   movl   %esp, %ebp
    0x22597a <+3>:   pushl  %ebx
```

So, this issue occurs in WatchKit code long before my code starts running, but it could be a problem with loading the storyboard, in which case I should try to find and fix it. Otherwise it could be another Xcode bug.  The prior Radar'd reports seem to be different circumstances. Is this another harmless Xcode report?